# Angularfire2 - Sorting objects based on one of it's values?

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

#### I'm trying to sort each object on it's date value and get each unique date.

Say we have a lot of such objects under a list in Firebase:

```
{
    object123: {
        date: "11-12-2016", 
        title: "These nuts"
    }
}
```

In part of the view I've got something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of uniqueDates">
  <h1>{{date}}</h1>
</div>
```

#### To get each unique date I've made an array `uniqueDates` which are supposed to contain each unique date.

To achieve this I tried to do like so:

```
 /* This was supposed to add each date value from all the objects to uniqueDates, 
 ** but did not work.
 ** "items" is a FirebaseListObservable
 */
 this.items.forEach(
   item => {item.subscribe(item => this.uniqueDates.push(item.date))}
 );

 /*This makes each value unique*/
 this.uniqueDates= Array.from(new Set(uniqueDates));
```

#### To get each object corresponding with the date I continue as so:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of uniqueDates">
  <h1>{{date}}</h1>

  <div *ngFor="let item of items | async"> //Items is a FirebaseListObservable containing all the objects
    <div *ngIf="item.date is equal to date">
      <p>{{item.someData}}<p>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this kind of approach I should go with? If so, how do I push each unique date to an array, the correct way? How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let flags:any = [];
let arrLength = this.items.length;
this.uniqueDates = [];

for(let count=0; i<arrLength; count++) {
  if(flags[this.items[count].date]) continue;
  flags[this.items[count].date] = true;
  this.uniqueDates.push(this.items[count]);
}
```

Now bind **uniqueDates** array to view. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you. With some modifications following this algorithm I got it working perfectly.